# How to create loading screen for Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, animation, splash-screen

I have a Java Swing program that has a lot of components and I want to implement a waiting animation that can be called on will (if it can be packaged all into one method call - not for just when the program begins). The idea is that I have two images that swoop in PowerPoint style --> wait for the components to be done --> the two images swoop out. I plan to do the animation for the two images in Java Swing (that is incrementing their x and y positions over time). Any ideas how I can go about this? I was thinking that I need a SwingWorker but I'm not very experienced with those. Is it even possible to know when Swing is done processing and painting all the components? Thank you.

Comment: Other similar questions: [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+swing+loading+screen+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: See also the AWT based (for good reason) [`SplashScreen`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/SplashScreen.html).